# Custom Font not loading React-Native

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo, custom-font

I'm trying to load a custom font from my assets folder within my project. I've looked up online and so far after doing all the steps, I'm still faced with the same issue.

I've added the source of the fonts into my package.json file like this:

```
"rnpm": {
    "assets": [
   "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
```

I've imported expo-font into my project as well, and I'm simply calling the fontFamily like this:

```
 <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular', fontSize: 20 }}>Home</Text>
```

am I missing something?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I'm using a custom font in another screen, the exact same way...yet this screen is giving me issues.

The files I am using are Montserrat-Regular.tff, Montserrat-Bold.tff, and Montserrate-Light.tff

The path for these files are MyProject/assets/fonts/MyFonts.ttf

Comment: Did you use `react-native link` after? And do you see the fonts in `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/`?

Comment: I've used `react-native link`, yet still no luck. My project doesn't have an android folder. I also forgot to mention that I'm using custom font on another screen and it compiles just fine. I don't understand why this screen in particular is giving me problems.

Comment: Hey, @FrankGully, Are you building an app for only iOS version?

Comment: Does this solve your issue?
[How to load custom fonts with the useFonts hook in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77172404)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an `Android` folder, so it looks like you're using `Expo`, not `React Native.`

So I'll show you how to do `Expo`.

1. Take the Open Sans zipfile that you downloaded, extract it and copy
   `Montserrat-Regular.ttf` into the `assets` directory in `your
   project`. The location we recommend is `your-project/assets/fonts.`
2. and you can run `expo install expo-font`
3. Add the following import in your application code in `App.js`: `import * as Font from 'expo-font';`
4. The expo library provides an API to access native functionality of
   the device from your JavaScript code. Font is the module that deals
   with font-related tasks. First, we must load the font from our
   assets directory using `Font.loadAsync()`. We can do this in the
   `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method of the App component. Add the
   following method in App: Now that we have the font files saved to
   disk and the Font SDK imported, let's add this code:

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    Font.loadAsync({
      'Montserrat-Regular': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
    });
  }

  // ...
}
```

This loads Open Sans Bold and associates it with the name `'Montserrat-Regular'` in `Expo's` font map. Now we just have to refer to this font in our `Text` component.

> **Note**: Fonts loaded through Expo don't currently support the `fontWeight` or `fontStyle` properties -- you will need to load those
>   variations of the font and specify them by name, as we have done here
>   with bold.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed steps. However this still doesn't work :( I've tried assigning the font to my text like this: `<Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Bold' }}>Home</Text>`

Comment: When I saw your question, `Montserrat-Regular` tried to save the font file. But you're trying to use `Montserrat-Bold` now. What do you want to register?

Comment: I have both files in my asset folder, and I tried the method you provided with both font styles. I just copied my code from the text in which is needed to be bold

Comment: Could you edit the files and code in your folder path and put it up in the question?

Comment: The font file has an extension of 'It's `.ttf`. Why is your file `.ttff`?

Comment: sorry that was a typo. it's `.ttf`

Comment: thank you for all your help. I managed to figure it out, but it was thanks to you that I was able to get the first step :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your Info.plist file from the iOS folder and looking for a UIAppFonts key, you should see something similar to:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
  <string>Montserrat Regular.ttf</string>
</array>
```

Also, your style will be like this;
`fontFamily: "Montserrat",` instead `fontFamily: "Montserrat-Regular"`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue I was having. It seems I needed to give the app a moment to load the font, still not sure why this was giving me the issue, but here is what my working code looks like now in case anybody else is having the same problem

This is the code I added into the screen in which I was trying to load my custom font.

```
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
  fontLoaded: false
}
}
 async componentDidMount(){
      await Font.loadAsync({
        'Montserrat': require('../assets/fonts/Montserrat.ttf'),
      }).then(() => {
      this.setState({fontLoaded: true})
    })

    }
<View>
{ this.state.fontLoaded == true ? (
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 40, fontFamily: 'Montserrat', color:'white', marginLeft: 10}}>Home</Text>
        ) : (<Text> Loading...</Text>)
      }
</View>
```